# Is EIP4337 UserOperation mempool a P2P decentralized mempool?

Tags: account-abstraction

I am checking the EIP-4337 bundler implementation recently and I find many implementations seem to only implement a private mempool for UserOps. For example, https://github.com/pimlicolabs/alto/blob/main/packages/mempool/src/mempool.ts, the mempool of Alto (bundler implementation by Pimlico) does not have any P2P communication code to exchange UserOps between different bundlers. So is the implementation by stackup: https://github.com/stackup-wallet/stackup-bundler/blob/main/pkg/mempool/instance.go

From my understanding, the mempool for EIP-4337 UserOps is supposed to be a permissionless, decentralized mempool like the Ethereum mempool for normal transactions to mitigate censorship and maintain fault-resistance. Am I understanding it incorrectly or am I missing anything in the current implementations?